# QGIS - selecting single polygon highlights multiple polygons

Tags: qgis, layers

I have two files,
One file is having GIS information of all the polygons which I want to display in QGIS. The other file contains the source polygon name from first file in one column, and the second column contains all other polygons related to the source polygon. Like this each polygon in first file as source and it contains multiple polygons in second column from same first file.

Now I want to see if I select one of the source polygon on map other related polygons should highlight.

Is there any way for that?

Comment: How are they linked?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3):

You could use Actions:

1. Open the layer properties and navigate to actions
2. Add a new Python action with the following code

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer('[%@layer_id%]')
field = 'my_field'
value = '[%my_field%]'
expr = f'"{field}" = \'{value}\''
layer.selectByExpression(expr)
```

Just change the name of your field.

[image]

Click on a feature using the action:

[image]